# PyQT list view not responding to datachanged signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qabstractlistmodel

I've been following some tutorials and trying to get a list model set up. My main window has two list views that are accessing the same model. When I update an item in one list, the other list doesn't update itself until it gets focus (I click on it). So it looks like the dataChanged signal isn't being emitted, but I can't work out how my code is different to any of the examples I'm basing it from.

**main.py**

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        # Test model and listviews
        data = [10,20,30,40,50]
        myModel = model.MyListModel(data)
        self.ui.listView.setModel(myModel)
        self.ui.listView_2.setModel(myModel)
```

**model.py**

```
class MyListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[], parent=None):
        super(MyListModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.__data)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            return str(self.__data[row])

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return 'Item at {0}'.format(row)

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            self.__data[index.row()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False
```

Can anyone see what is wrong here? FYI I'm using PyQT5.2.1 and Python 3.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the signature of `dataChanged` signal. In Qt4 it looked like this:

```
    dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight)
```

but in Qt5, it looks like this:

```
    dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight,
                const QVector<int> & roles = QVector<int>())
```

when I tried your example code with PyQt-5.1.1, I got an error when attempting to emit the signal without the third argument. Strictly speaking, this was incorrect behaviour, because the third argument has a default value. So this is perhaps why the behaviour has changed.

But it seems that you must now explicitly emit an empty list as the third argument of `dataChanged` in order for things to work properly in PyQt5:

```
    self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [])
```

or, of course, emit a list of the roles that have actually been changed:

```
    self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [QtCore.Qt.EditRole])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working as intended now. There's so many web examples for Qt4 and very little for Qt5, and all the little differences are catching me out.

Comment: note that if you ever want to emit this from another thread, that is not supported by qt. Data items cannot travel across threads.
You would keep getting the error about registering QVector<int>.
The solution is to explicitly pass a "emit" command from thread1 to the qt/main thread and do the emit from there,

Comment: @MMM. Data most certainly can be emitted across threads safely. It seems that you may have discovered a bug. Is the error coming from Qt, or PyQt (i.e. do you get a python traceback)?

Comment: yes. It is because of this.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46517
Qt don't really support emitting datamodel items across threads.
As they refused to register QVector<int>, when using queued connections (across threads signal emitting), that particular signal cannot be emitted as of now.

because emitting from the main thread doesn't use queued connections, the same signal is emitted successfully when I used the main thread

Comment: @MMM. Actually, the signal *can* be emitted, so long as the relevant types have been registered first. This would only be thread-safe if the model wasn't connected to a view, though. And since models usually *are* connected to views, I suppose it makes sense that Qt doesn't register the types by default.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, ())
```

do not work for me (python 2.7, PyQt5).

But one of the following will work:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [])
```

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, list())
```