# PyQt5 signals and threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, pyqt5

In PyQt5 under Python 3, I am trying to use a `QTableView` for showing the state of my domain objects, keeping the view updated whenever the domain objects change. My domain objects should not need to know anything about this view or PyQt in particular, but using a kind of observer pattern, each domain object has a list of callback functions that are run when the state of the object changes, and from the PyQt side I provide callbacks that emit signals connected to the view.

The thing is, I run into problems apparently to do with threading; in a nutshell it seems that the signals that should be fired are indeed fired, and apparently to the correct amount of slots, but that the slots are not called.

The attached code gives a somewhat minimal example. A domain object has a name and an integer value. This value can be modified in two ways: it can be increased by one right away, or it can be increased by one in a second. The latter operation is implemented with `threading.Timer`.

The model/view-oriented GUI shows a table of the current domain objects, one per row, and has two pushbuttons corresponding to the two ways of modifying the object value. The signal that is causing me trouble is `dataChanged`, and for debugging, this is connected to an `onDataChanged` slot in the view, that prints its arguments to the console when it is called.

When selecting e.g. the second row and clicking "Increase value", the signal/slot mechanism works fine: the value is updated in the view, and the console shows

```
Emitting dataChanged to 4 receivers...
dataChanged signal detected: (1, 0) / (1, 1)
...done emitting
```

However, when clicking "Increase value in a second", the view is *not* updated until this is forced in some other way (e.g. selecting another row). Also, the console output makes it clear that the `onDataChanged` is not called (which is of course just another symptom of the same problem):

```
Emitting dataChanged to 4 receivers...
...done emitting
```

So, what's going on and how do I fix it? I've found various mentions that threading and the PyQt signalling mechanism may not work well together, but haven't quite grasped exactly what is wrong with what I'm trying. I've seen Qt-specific threading being recommended instead of the Python `threading` module, but I would *very* strongly prefer that my domain data be kept totally independent of Qt stuff. (Also, even if in this toy example it would be easy enough to control the one-second delay from the model/view side, in my real app this behaviour truly belongs in the domain objects themselves.)

Any enlightenment or ideas?

```
import sys
from threading import Timer
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp, QApplication, QWidget, QTableView, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout

class MyDomainObject(object):
    '''Class representing something in the real world: a name associated with an integer.

    To keep interested parties up to date, each instance has a list of callbacks, functions
    which are called with self as argument when the integer is changed.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.callbacks = []

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)

    def increase_value(self):
        self.value += 1
        self.notify_observers() 

    def increase_value_in_a_second(self):
        Timer(1, self.increase_value).start()

    def notify_observers(self): 
        for cb in self.callbacks:
            cb(self)

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    '''Model class holding a list of domain objects for showing in a view'''
    COLS = ['name', 'value']

    def __init__(self, obj_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.obj_list = obj_list
        for row, obj in enumerate(self.obj_list):
            obj.add_callback(self.callbackFactory(row))

    #########################
    # MANDATORY OVERRIDES

    def rowCount(self, dummy):
        return len(self.obj_list)

    def columnCount(self, dummy):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return getattr(self.obj_list[index.row()], self.COLS[index.column()])

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    # MANDATORY OVERRIDES end
    #########################

    def callbackFactory(self, row):
        '''Factory method making function emitting a dataChanged signal for given row.'''
        def _callback(ignored_obj):
            model_index_left = self.createIndex(row, 0)
            model_index_right = self.createIndex(row, 1)
            print('Emitting dataChanged to {} receivers...'.format(self.receivers(self.dataChanged)))
            self.dataChanged.emit(model_index_left, model_index_right)
            print('...done emitting')
            qApp.processEvents()
        return _callback

    def at(self, ix):
        '''For convenience: Return domain object at given index.'''
        try:
            return self.obj_list[ix]
        except IndexError:
            return None

class MyTableView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QTableView(self)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.table.model().dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)
        # Select whole rows, single selection only:
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        # Two ways of increasing value: now, or slightly later:
        self.increase_button = QPushButton('Increase value', self)
        self.increase_button.clicked.connect(self.onIncreaseClicked)
        self.increase_later_button = QPushButton('Increase value in a second', self)
        self.increase_later_button.clicked.connect(self.onIncreaseLaterClicked)

        self.sel_model = self.table.selectionModel()

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.table)
        hbox.addWidget(self.increase_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.increase_later_button)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

    def onDataChanged(self, top_left_ix, bottom_right_ix):
        print('dataChanged signal detected: ({}, {}) / ({}, {})'.format(top_left_ix.row(), top_left_ix.column(),
                                                                    bottom_right_ix.row(), bottom_right_ix.column()))

    def onIncreaseClicked(self):
        selected = self.sel_model.selectedIndexes() # either empty, or all have the same row.
        if selected:
            selected_obj = self.table.model().at(selected[0].row())
            selected_obj.increase_value()

    def onIncreaseLaterClicked(self):
        selected = self.sel_model.selectedIndexes() # either empty, or all have the same row.
        if selected:
            selected_obj = self.table.model().at(selected[0].row())
            selected_obj.increase_value_in_a_second()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    domain_objects = [MyDomainObject('Foo', 23), MyDomainObject('Bar', 0)]
    model = MyTableModel(domain_objects)
    view = MyTableView(model)
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sleep and further googling may have yielded the solution:

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560296/pyqt-list-view-not-responding-to-datachanged-signal) that while such interthread signalling works in general, the PyQt5 `dataChanged` signal in particular has a quirk which gives this behaviour: a third, optional argument with the `QVector<int>` C++ signature, which apparently isn't registered in Qt as a metatype (caveat: I don't really know what I'm talking about there), something that the developers seem to have [declined to fix](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46517).

My solution has been to have the model define and emit a custom `myDataChanged` signal, and connect it to a slot back in the view, which *then* asks the model to emit the built-in `dataChanged` signal to make the under-the-hood wiring do its refresh things. In the posted code, make the following changes:

- At the top, add the line

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
  ```
- At the start of the `MyTableModel` class, add the line

  ```
  myDataChanged = pyqtSignal('QModelIndex', 'QModelIndex')
  ```
- In `MyTableModel.callbackFactory`, replace `dataChanged` with `myDataChanged` (one actual code occurrence, plus two in comments/strings to keep things pretty).
- In `MyTableView.__init__`, replace `dataChanged` with `myDataChanged` (one occurrence).
- In `MyTableView.onDataChanged`, add the line

  ```
  self.table.model().dataChanged.emit(top_left_ix, bottom_right_ix)
  ```